# How do I merge composer manager composer.json with core 8.3 composer.json?

Tags: updating, composer

I was using Drupal 8.0.5 site with composer manager. Now I want to upgrade core to 8.3.2 which comes with composer.

Composer Manager asked me to uninstall this module, as it is no longer supported in core 8.3.

How can I merge old composer.json with new composer.json supplied by core 8.3.

Comment: I asked a question similar to this when I stopped using Composer Manager: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225720/running-drupal-composer-update-no-longer-works <--My solution was to use wildcards in the merge-plugin include section in that post, like so: `"modules/custom/*/composer.json"`